# Taint InstanceGroup on Kubernetes using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I can taint a node but not an instance group.

```
kubectl taint nodes nodeA 
kops.k8s.io/instancegroup=loadbalancer:NoSchedule
```

can we do below

```
kubectl taint instanceGroup loadbalancer:NoSchedule 


error: at least one taint update is required
```

Answer (score 4):

Instance Group is [GCP thing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/) and not a Kubernetes thing. Taints can only be done on nodes. So you will have to taint the nodes manually.

If you named the nodes in your instance group to something that matches `mygroup`. For example, you could do something like this:

```
$ kubectl taint nodes `kubectl get nodes -o name | grep mygroup` key=value:NoSchedule
```

Comment: `kubectl get nodes -o name | grep mygroup`